# timeout TCP Windows 8 - Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, timeout

I browse with Firefox, and i get a timetout TCP on a webpage.

I heard that **network.http.response.timeout** in Firefox (about:config) is **no longer used**.

How to change timetout TCP setting on Windows ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Comment: @MarcB ok thanks, i will ask to microsoft support